# Sync clock over ethernet using custom message

Tags: c#, ethernet

I have a setup where I have some PLC's connected to a windows PC, I am doing the code on the windows PC in C#. I want to be able to sync the clock of the PLC's with the PC.

The PLC don't support the windows built in time sync services, so I need to do it myself.

My first idea is to just send a message (TCP) to the PLC periodically containing the time of the windows PC. I don't need to be precise on milliseconds, a second would be fine. So my first guess is that this would be enough.

But now I think that if it wasn't so difficult it could be cool to make something that took the time of sending a message on TCP into account to get a more precise sync.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Check if the PLC support any established time sync protocol before you invent your own. Most PLCs appears to support one of the standard protocols.Sample code that ships with the PLC usually contains some kind of clock syncing code.

Answer (score 1):

Since TCP has some overhead and the amount of data is pretty small, why not use UDP?

Send a UDP request to the server, receive the current time as answer and use half of the answer time as transport delay - rough but easy to do.

Comment: The socket is already used for other messages and uses a standard protocol which runs on TCP. I don't have the option to change the prrotocol, only add some extra information to the messages and handling of messages in both ends.

Comment: Either way, if there's a significant delay on the transmission, the easiest way is to time a query/answer delay. Either you request the time from the server and time the delay or you acknowledge a pushed server message and it responds with the delay it has timed.